# shell_exec() not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, shell, codeigniter

shell_exec() is not working in codeigniter. but, this command working in terminal.
Output:00:00:30.11

`$input="/opt/lampp/htdocs/images/fish5.flv";
 $time      =   shell_exec("ffmpeg -i $input 2>&1 | grep 'Duration' | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed s/,//");`

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a support question.

Answer (score 0):

When you debug you web-app that has to execute the shell_exec() you should see the detailed error. Did you try this? (console from the browser)

Probably you are trying to access a folder with restricted permissions (The user that runs the web server can't access that directory). Give your webserver permission with `chmod` to access this directory and try running your command again. It should work.

Alex

Answer (score 0):

"Not working" is not a useful diagnostic. What does happen? Have you checked that your error logging/reporting is correctly configured to capture errors? What is in your logs?

"this command working in terminal" - what do you mean? Are you just running the string you pass to shell_exec or are you running the PHP script from the command line? The latter would reveal if shell_exec is excluded as a [disabled function](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) (but note that the CLI SAPI may use a different php.ini than the web sapi).

Beyond that, potential causes are:

- permissions on the data files
- permissions on the executables
- the PATH variable not being populated to reference the executables in the webserver environment
- the webserver may be running chroot
- SELinux / Apparmor restrictions

Comment: Command line result, 

http://imgur.com/a/Dg2sX

whereas we get empty in codeigniter api,

$input="/opt/lampp/htdocs/images/fish5.flv";
 $time      =   shell_exec("ffmpeg -i $input 2>&1 | grep 'Duration' | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed s/,//");